# Cocos2D. iPad loads retina graphics on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, retina-display

The question is very simple. When running on iOS 6 iPad is loading resources with suffix `~ipad-hd` instead of just `~ipad`. Have you ever run into this issue? How do i fix it?

Comment: Which iPad are you testing on?

Comment: @JamesWebster iPad2. it behaves the same on iPad iOS 6.0 simulator

Comment: by default, extension for iPad are, image-ipad.png, image-ipadhd.png  not image~ipad-hd.png